# SpringBoot 2.1.9.RELEASE - reading resource file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, resources

I want to read a resouce file, 
doing this it works fine:

```
HostelPayload hostelPayload = objectMapper.readValue(new File("C:/Users/sandro/IdeaProjects/bendiciones/src/test/resources/files/hostel_resource.json"), HostelPayload.class);
```

but when I do this

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("classpath:files/hostel_resource.json");
HostelPayload hostelPayload = objectMapper.readValue(resource.getFile(), HostelPayload.class);
```

I got this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classpath:files/hostel_resource.json] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the statement

`new ClassPathResource("classpath:files/hostel_resource.json")`

It should be just

`new ClassPathResource("files/hostel_resource.json")`

You don't need to add `classpath` to file paths when reading files using Spring's `ClassPathResource`

Spring internally uses `java.lang.ClassLoader` to resolve the complete path of the file.